# What exactly does the return line (dotted line) represents in a sequence diagram?

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram

In which kind of steps should be we use the return line in a sequence diagram?

```
<- - - - - -
```

Comment: I've updated my answer with my comments on your seq diagram and questions

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The return line represents the flow of control returning from a method/function call

In the case of methods/functions that return a result, it would indicate a value is being returned.

E.g.

```
    result
<-------------
```

Otherwise, for void methods/functions it would just be the arrow

```
<-------------
```

For asynchronous calls, as the caller doesn't yield control to the invoked method/function, I would only use a return line if it returned a result (e.g. non-void methods/functions)

Hope that helps

**EDIT**

Here is an example of a sequence diagram I created for a search use case
[example of a sequence diagram I created for a search use case http://web10.twitpic.com/img/107669708-1d6f9df82534756bfe2a684d4480cc43.4c00f3b0-full.png](http://web10.twitpic.com/img/107669708-1d6f9df82534756bfe2a684d4480cc43.4c00f3b0-full.png)

Note that the Anonymous user only makes asynchronous calls because, as a human being, they do not yield control to the application, hence no return arrows

Also note the return arrow of the search() call, which returns 'results'

Finally, the creation arrows ( ------|> ) do not have return arrows as they implicitly return the instantiated object

**EDIT 2**

In response to your updated question:

I would not have return arrows for operations by the user, such as login(), as the results are not returned to the user in the same manner as an  object, but normally outputted to some kind of UI. Another way of looking at it is that the user is outside the scope of the program, so it doesn't make sense to return results directly.

From your diagram, my interpretation (in a kind of pseudocode) would be:

```
class User{
    public void login()
    public void sendEmail()
}

class Patient{
    public void getPatient()
}

class Doctor{
    public void getDoctor()
}

class Appointment{
    //This method returns something, but it's not clear what, so I assumed a boolean
    public boolean checkAvailability()
}
```

As you can see, all but one of these methods do not return anything. If that's what you wanted then good, but I suspect that's not the case.

I also suspect you did not intend for the sendEmail() method to be in the User class.

You should also consider what is happening when checkAvailability() returns, as the the flow of control seems to return to User and then inexplicably jump back to Appointment

Comment: The objects in a sequence diagram should always correspond to an object in the class diagram, or can be included more?

Comment: They would normally correspond to a class in a class diagram, yes. I should also note that the Actor (Anonymous User) should be depicted as a stick man, but the program I used for this doesn't fully support UML2 yet

Comment: OK according to this I feel now like I have a big mess.
What Im trying to model is the following:
A user login in the system as a patient (role) to ask for an appointment.
The patient should enter doctor and then date. System should verify the availability for that date, if theres avilability should create the new appointment and send an email to the user.

If user login as a doctor(role) it goes different but now I dont want to include that

The email im not sure if tis ok

Comment: I see what you're trying to achieve, but don't have the time right now to give my suggestions. Hopefully you're able to wait until Sunday when I'll be able to give a suitable response

Comment: Well, perhaps not. However, I think that we're beginning to stray away from the original question. You should consider posting a new question asking the best way to approach/design the use case you describe (if you do ask it in a new question, if you link to in a comment I can look at it when I'm back)

Answer (score 4):

It represents the return message of the operation.You can specify return values using this symbol.

Answer (score 3):

Simple example:

```
club                       member
  |
  |           getName()
  '------------------------>.
                            |
                            |
       result: "lee"        |
   <- - - - - - - - - - - - '

 String memberName = member.getName();
 //memberName now contains "lee"
```

The dashed arrow <- - - - is the return value from the method call.